# How to make the dynamic React Router static?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

The React Router used to be static but in version 4 it became dynamic. That has many advantages but in some cases you rather have the React components independent of the router. For example if you are upgrading to React Router v4 and don‘t want to make too many changes, or if you want to keep your components clean of any router functionality for the sake of reusability.

How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to make your components free of the router functionality.

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link} from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => (
  <Router>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route path="/items" component={ItemsRouter} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
);

const ItemsRouter = (props) => {
  if (props.match.isExact)
    return <ItemsList/>

  return (
    <Route exact path={`${props.match.url}/:itemId`} component={Item} />
  );
};

const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>Home page</h2>
    <Link to="/items">Check out the items</Link>
  </div>
);

const ItemsList = () => (
  <div>
    <h2>List of items</h2>
    <ul>
      <ol><Link to="/items/item1">Item 1</Link></ol>
      <ol><Link to="/items/item2">Item 2</Link></ol>
    </ul>
  </div>
);

const Item = ({match}) => {
  let itemName;

  switch (match.params.itemId) {
    case 'item1':
      itemName = 'Item 1';
      break;
    case 'item2':
      itemName = 'Item 2';
      break;
    default:
      itemName = 'Unknown item';
  }

  return <h2>Details for {`${itemName}`}</h2>
}

export default App;
```